# I have an unindent error while using geany with python

Tags: python, indentation

I'm using geany and I get the following error

```
  File "autoblog2.py", line 9
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

here is my code.

```
import urllib
import re

symbols_list = ["aapl","spy","goog","nflx"]

i = 0
while i<len(symbols_list):
    url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s='+symbols_list[i]
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">(.+?)'+symbols_list[i]'</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print 'the price of' +symbols_list[i]
    i+=1
```

I don't get any errors when I run the same code on a single url. I've only had since trying it with a while loop, i'm using python 2

Comment: My guess is you swapped between tabs and spaces between `htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)` and the line above it.

Comment: @That1Guy i would say the same thing , pyhton is super picky when it comes to these kinds of things

Comment: allright thanks, that was the problem I've sorted the indent error I'm just getting a invallid syntax error where I've replaced +symbolslist[i] with the price variable in the print statement.

Comment: @Paradizigmania I wouldn't say Python is picky. In fact, its pretty lenient. While in your editor, four spaces and `\t` might _appear_ the same, they're actually different characters. How can Python know that four spaces means the same as `\t`? What if you use three spaces in your editor? Should it also accept that as equal to one tab? What about two spaces? five? You see the problem here. To account for this, Python doesn't care how many spaces or tabs you use as indent as long as you're consistent within the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when you edit one script with two editors.
Your indent settings can differ from editor to editor.
Take a look at the script with another editor.
If the script has the same indents in other editors the only way is to remove all indents and add them again.
I would recommend the python-idle. 
It should show the indents like the interpreter reads them.
Good Luck.